# How to remove duplicate values from array in foreach loop?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, duplicates, array-unique

I want to remove duplicate values from array. I know to use `array_unique(array)` function but faced problem in `foreach` loop. This is not a duplicate question because I have read several questions regarding this and most of them force to use `array_unique(array)` function but I have no idea to use it in `foreach` loop. Here is my php function.

```
$images = scandir($dir);
$listImages=array();
foreach($images as $image){
    $listImages=$image;
    echo substr($listImages, 0, -25) ."<br>"; //remove last 25 chracters
}
```

How to do this?

Comment: can you post ur expected output and input

Comment: please specify your full example

Comment: yes you can use array_unique after ending your foreach loop.

Comment: `Use array_unique()` ?? something like `array_unique($images)`

Comment: Your code is nothing to do with what you say. If you want to delete duplicates from an array in an alternative way please use a double iteration classic pattern

Comment: Looking at your code, `$images` should already contain a unique array of filenames (no OS allows for duplicate filenames. The closest you can come is *nix case-sensative filenames, e.g. `ab.txt` != `AB.txt`, but is still a valid unique filename). Could you explain what it is you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is very complicated to remove duplicate values from array within foreach loop. Simply you can push all elements to one array and then remove the duplicates and then get values as you need. Try with following code.

```
   $listImages=array();
   $images = scandir($dir);

   foreach($images as $image){
       $editedImage = substr($image, 0, -25);
       array_push($listImages, $editedImage);
   } 

   $filteredList = array_unique($listImages);

   foreach($filteredList as $oneitem){
       echo $oneitem;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

The example you provided could be modified as follows:

```
$images = scandir($dir);
$listImages=array();
foreach($images as $image) {
    if (!in_array($image, $listImages)) {
        $listImages[] = $image;
    }
    echo substr($image, 0, -25) ."<br>"; //remove last 25 chracters
}
```

Now `$listImages` will contain no duplicates, and it will echo every image (including duplicates).

Comment: @ mister martin, it will be optimized if will use `array_unique($listImages)`  after loop end. for now you did check everytime in loop.

Comment: why to down vote... if answer is correct and different from you @mister martin

Comment: I want to print each and every value within the foreach loop. So cant use `array_unique($listImages)` after loop end

Answer (score 1):

Based on @mistermartins answer:

```
$images = scandir($dir);
$listImages=array();
foreach($images as $image) {
    //if already echo'd continue to next iteration
    if (in_array($image, $listImages)) {
        continue;
    }
    //else, add image to array and echo.
    $listImages[] = $image;
    echo substr($image, 0, -25) ."<br>"; //remove last 25 chracters
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be faster to use hashmaps:

```
$images = scandir($dir);
$listImages = array();
foreach($images as $image) {
    if (!isset($listImages[$image])) {
        $listImages[$image] = true;
        echo substr($image, 0, -25) ."<br>"; //remove last 25 chracters
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I have understood you completely. Subsequent approach worked for me in order to remove duplicate indizes from array using a foreeach loop.

```
$list = array("hans", "peter", "hans", "lara", "peter", "lara", "lara");
sort($list);
foreach ($list as $k => $v) {
     if (isset($check)) {
        if ($check === $v) {
            unset($list[$k]);
        }
     }
     $check = $v;
}

$noDuplicate = array_values($list);

print_r($noDuplicate);
```

gives following result:

Array ( [0] => hans [1] => lara [2] => peter )